# FATAL: Data file was created with a Redis server configured to handle more than 1 databases. Exiting

Tags: redis

I have one redis instance and my redis.conf file is:

```
# masterauth [password]
# requirepass [password]
bind 0.0.0.0
protected-mode no
# port 6379
tcp-backlog 511
timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 300
pidfile /var/run/redis_6380.pid

loglevel verbose

#databases 1


stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename dump.rdb

dir /data

appendonly no
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"

# appendfsync always
appendfsync everysec
# appendfsync no
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof-load-truncated yes
aof-use-rdb-preamble no

lua-time-limit 5000

slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 128

latency-monitor-threshold 0

notify-keyspace-events ""

hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64

list-max-ziplist-size -2
list-compress-depth 0

set-max-intset-entries 512

zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64

hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000

activerehashing yes

client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit slave 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60

hz 10

aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes

maxmemory 1000mb
maxmemory-policy volatile-ttl


port 6379

databases 1

requirepass [password]

masterauth [password]
```

but my redis can not start!!!

logs:

22:C 19 Aug 2021 07:39:51.385 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
22:C 19 Aug 2021 07:39:51.385 # Redis version=5.0.7, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=22, just started
22:C 19 Aug 2021 07:39:51.385 # Configuration loaded
22:M 19 Aug 2021 07:39:51.387 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
22:M 19 Aug 2021 07:39:51.387 # Server initialized
22:M 19 Aug 2021 07:39:51.468 # FATAL: Data file was created with a Redis server configured to handle more than 1 databases. Exiting

ERROR is:

```
22:M 19 Aug 2021 07:39:51.468 # FATAL: Data file was created with a Redis server configured to handle more than 1 databases. Exiting
```

**what am i doing??**

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!!!

I was deployed in k8s and using PVC. I don't know why, but after remove PVC and bound new one, this error was fixed